# Understanding API response from Laravel 5 Dingo/Api Using AngularJs; What's the correct JSON Format

Tags: php, angularjs, api, laravel, dingo-api

I am building an API for a Laravel 5 Web application using AngularJs App as API consumer.

Everything works perfectly except for the response returned from the API when a call is made from AngularJS.

**Here is what I have in AngularJs App which also uses Satellizer**

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', [
        'ngResource',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'dialogs.main',
        'ui.router',
        'satellizer',
        'ui.router.stateHelper',
        'templates'
    ]);


app.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'modalStateProvider', '$authProvider',
    function($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, modalStateProvider, $authProvider)
    {

        var modalInstance,
            modalExit = function() {
                if (modalInstance) {
                    //alert('modalInstance exit');
                    modalInstance.close();
                }
            };

        // Satellizer configuration that specifies which API
        // route the JWT should be retrieved from
        $authProvider.loginUrl = '/api/authenticate';

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


 $stateProvider
            .state('profile',{
                url: '/profile',
                views: {
                    'contentFullRow': {
                        templateUrl: 'ng/templates/profile/partials/profile-heading-one.html',
                        controller: function($scope, profile){
                            $scope.profile  = profile;
                        }
                    },
                    'contentLeft': {
                        templateUrl: 'ng/templates/profile/partials/profile-body-one.html',
                        controller: function($scope, profile){
                            $scope.profile = profile;
                        }
                    },
                    'sidebarRight': {
                        templateUrl: 'ng/templates/profile/partials/todo-list-one.html',
                        controller: function($scope, profile){
                            $scope.profile = profile;
                        }
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    profile: function($http){
                        return $http.get('/api/profile').then(function(data){
                            //This is the issue, I am doing this because of the response returned
                            return data.data.profile;
                        });


                    }
                }
            });


        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        };

    }]);
```

**In my Laravel Controller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Profile;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->middleware('api.auth');
     }

    public function getIndex(){

        $user = $this->auth->user();

        return Profile::find($user->id);
    }
}
```

**Response from Laravel**
[image]

**The challenge I have is in the response above.**

As you can see in the `resolve` method of Angular Ui Router,
To get the profile object from the returned JSON, I had to do this:

```
return $http.get('/api/profile').then(function(data){
   return data.data.profile;
});
```

How do I make the API to return only profile object without `config`, `header` and other objects sent along? Are they really necessary? I would like to simply do this:

```
return $http.get('/api/profile').then(function(data){
   return data; //which contains only profile object
});
```

**Edited:**
**I think my question is; Is this the right JSON response Format from Dingo Api?**

```
{
  "config",
  "data": {
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Wing"
  },
  "headers",
  "status",
  "statusText"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to return a response from the controller, not an Eloquent object:

http://laravel.com/docs/master/responses.

You can specify what exactly you need there (like profile).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. perhaps little example will be helpful

Comment: Well, it depends on what exactly do you have in the `Profile` object, but it could be something like `    public function getIndex(){

        $user = $this->auth->user();

        $u = Profile::find($user->id);
        return response()->json(['profile' => $u->profile]);
    }`